# Question about local NFB in a transistor

Tags: transistors, amplifier, filter, feedback

I've seen this a few times and I can't seem to find documentation so maybe I'm not understanding what's happening here. My interpretation is that the transistor is configured as a common emitter and the circled capacitor is acting as a high pass filter, passing the inverted signal back to the base, thus attenuating the higher frequencies.

Is this a correct understanding, and if so, how exactly do I calculate the effect?

And also, if you could point out further reading on the topic, I'd appreciate it.

[image: Transistor with capacitor between base and collector]

Comment: You can't calculate the effect (or any effect) from the pasted partial circuit image.

Comment: I'm not asking for an answer to the specific case. I'm asking for the general case. If I have a transistor set up as a common-emitter amplifier and I have a capacitor between the collector and base, how do I calculate the effect (which I assume is LNFB) on the output signal of the amplifier?

Comment: I think it would be termed a shunt-shunt feedback. Looks like [example 8.3 in slide 56 here](http://cc.ee.nchu.edu.tw/~aiclab/teaching/Electronics3/lect08.pdf)

Comment: Similar, but in my case I'm asking about the case of a capacitor only and no resistor. I don't understand how to account for that difference. I'm not an EE, I'm just a hobbyist with a lot of holes in my knowledge, so sorry for my lack of understanding.

Comment: A short study of Miller Effect might help you understand what happens due to the capacitor

Comment: If you are familiar with representing the impedance of a capacitor as \$1/(j\omega C)\$, I think you will be able to adapt the same theory for the resistor example to your capacitor example.

Comment: @nn08 Thank you. I understand now.

Comment: @AJN Thank you. That was very helpful as well.

Comment: @Pete Cheers mate :)